# Using an output file stored on the OpenCPU server as input to a subsequent function call

Tags: opencpu

**Question:** how can I use an output file stored on the OpenCPU server as input to another function?

**Background:**
I am attempting to use `knitr` and `markdown` within openCPU to generate html that I can use to update a webpage with statistical information on the page load.

The basic workflow is as follows:

1. Generate an .Rmd file, store locally.
2. Access a webpage that uses AJAX to upload the .Rmd file to an OpenCPU instance on the server.
3. Use the `knit` function via openCPU to turn the function into a *.md file stored on the server.
4. Use the `markdownToHTML` function on the file stored on the server (by passing in the appropriate hash generated via the call to `knit`) and receive an AJAX reply that contains the generated HTML.
5. Update web page with new HTML.

As it stands, I have this process working up to step 4. I can call `knit` passing in an .Rmd file via a form request POST, and I receive the following reply from OpenCPU:

```
{
"object" : "xa9eaea44e1",
"graphs" : [
    "xf31dcfe7f3"
],
"files" : {
    "figure" : "xfc55396fd8",
    "test.md" : "x7821c69f79"
}
}
```

where `"test.md"` is the output file generated via the `knit` function. Now, I attempt to use the hash (in this case `"x7821c69f79"` by POSTing to `/R/pub/markdown/markdownToHTML/ascii` with the following parameters:

```
file     /R/tmp/x7821c69f79/bin
```

This returns an `HTTP 400` error with the following message:

```
cannot open URL 'http://localhost/R/store/R/tmp/x7821c69f79/bin/rds'
```

However, when I make a GET request to `/R/tmp/x7821c69f79/bin`, the contents of `test.md` are returned. So I know the file is being stored correctly on the call to `knit`.

So, what's going on here? In other words, **how can I use an output file stored on the OpenCPU server as input to another function?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hmz the `/store` error looks like a bug, I'll look into that.

Maybe in step 3 you can have the function return the contents of `test.md`, e.g. end with `return(readLines(test.md))`? Or better yet, don't output to `test.md` but to a `tmpfile()` and return the contents of that. This way the output is stored as an R object in the store, rather than a raw file, and you can just pass an argument e.g. `file=x7821c69f79` in step 4.

Did you have a look at the [markdown example app](http://public.opencpu.org/apps/opencpu.demo/markdown)? See source [here](https://github.com/jeroenooms/opencpu.demo/blob/master/R/knithtml.R) and [here](https://github.com/jeroenooms/opencpu.demo/tree/master/inst/opencpu/apps/markdown).

Comment: outputting to a tmpfile() was what I originally wanted, that way I could circumvent the file storage issue altogether. However, based on the knitr documentation it appears as though the knit function will only output to a file. I could still wrap it in my own function, perhaps, and have that return the file's contents such that they're stored in an R object in the store.

Man...how did I miss the markdown/knitr examples! I'll look into those.